# Not able to select the right data

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have been handed a legacy xml which is not going to change.
In formatted way it looks like this:

```
<Result>
    <StepSequence>
      <RealMeasure>
        <Text value="Batman"/>
      </RealMeasure>
    </StepSequence>
    <StepSequence>
      <RealMeasure>
        <Text value="Superman"/>
      </RealMeasure>
    </StepSequence>
</Result>
```

Actually it comes like this:

```
<Result><StepSequence><RealMeasure><Text value="Batman"/></RealMeasure></StepSequence><StepSequence><RealMeasure><Text value="Superman"/></RealMeasure></StepSequence></Result>
```

Regex I have come up with is:

```
<RealMeasure><((\w*)\s+value="(.*)".*?)></RealMeasure>
```

But it is selecting data:

```
<RealMeasure><Text value="Batman"/></RealMeasure></StepSequence><StepSequence><RealMeasure><Text value="Superman"/></RealMeasure>
```

I want to select: 
`<RealMeasure><Text value="Batman"/></RealMeasure>`

and

`<RealMeasure><Text value="Superman"/></RealMeasure>`

I want to get groups so that I can later convert the match to something like:
`<RealMeasure type="Text" value="Superman"/>`

using pattern like:

```
<RealMeasure type="$2" value=$3>
```

[Link to online regex tester](http://regexr.com/4v732)

Any tips to improve my regex?

Comment: You got a very greedy quantifier just after the dot, meaning it will match anything up to the last quote.

Comment: Are there ways to make it efficient? I am not a regex expert. Matching will happen quite a lot and will have performance implications. If you can suggest something more efficient please add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```js
let reg = /<RealMeasure><((\w+)\s+value="(.*?)".*?)><\/RealMeasure>/g;
let str= `<Result><StepSequence><RealMeasure><Text value="Batman"/></RealMeasure></StepSequence><StepSequence><RealMeasure><Text value="Superman"/></RealMeasure></StepSequence></Result>`;
str.replace(reg, `<RealMeasure type="$2" value="$3"/>`); //<Result><StepSequence><RealMeasure type="Text" value="Batman"/></StepSequence><StepSequence><RealMeasure type="Text" value="Superman"/></StepSequence></Result>
```

The group `value="(.*?)"` has to be non-greedy as well. And changed the `(\w*)` to `(\w+)` to ensure that type is not empty.

Also, `/` in `</RealMeasure>` has to be escaped like `<\/RealMeasure>`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following regex:

```
<RealMeasure><(\w+).*?("[^"]*").*?<\/RealMeasure>
```

and it seems to be doing exactly what you want.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/iBbixC/1). Detailed explanations are to the right-hand side of the page.

Please note that the software that you use might impose some limitations to the regex features that you can use.

Alternatively, use a **proper XML parser** to extract and reformat the data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not an expert in regex so cannot judge if it is preformant over what others have suggested. If you feel it is more preformant then please add details if possible.

Comment: How do you define "performant"? You did not even specify what software you want to use for handling the regex. I guess that the most performant is the proper XML parser which I suggested in the first place, especially considering that you want to extract and handle data, change the layout...

Comment: I am using Logstash (one of product from Elastic) to process this xml into individual data items. They support these [regex formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html).